Virtualbox stopped working (Package has no installation candidate)
I'm using a Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS desktop and have been successfully hosting VMs via virtualbox 6.1.32, until I got the following error:

Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)
The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up correctly. Please reinstall virtualbox-dkms package and load the kernel module by executing
'modprobe vboxdrv' as root.

When I reinstall the virtualbox-dkms package, it tries to build for 6.8.0-40-generic, though those kernel headers seem to be missing:
sudo apt-get reinstall virtualbox-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/718 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 179503 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../virtualbox-dkms_6.1.32-dfsg-1build1_amd64.deb ...
Deleting module virtualbox-6.1.32 completely from the DKMS tree.
Unpacking virtualbox-dkms (6.1.32-dfsg-1build1) over (6.1.32-dfsg-1build1) ...
Setting up virtualbox-dkms (6.1.32-dfsg-1build1) ...
Loading new virtualbox-6.1.32 DKMS files...
Building for 6.8.0-40-generic
Module build for kernel 6.8.0-40-generic was skipped since the
kernel headers for this kernel does not seem to be installed.

I unsuccessfully tried apt-get install linux-headers-uname -r:
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

I also tried to (re-) install various version of virtualbox (e.g. 7.0_7.0.20), virtualbox-ext-pack (even though it worked fine without before it) to no avail.
When I try apt-get install linux-headers, only headers with the version 5.15 and 5.17 instead of 6.8.0-40 get listed. Could this part of the issue?
Since I'm inexperienced when it comes to Linux: Is it possible that somehow the wrong headers are referenced? How can I fix this?

Since you're using standard Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, you should be able to install VirtualBox without need to rebuild it. Have you tried tutorial at https://linuxconfig.org/install-virtualbox-on-ubuntu-22-04-jammy-jellyfish-linux?

Yes, this is where I started and it worked for over a year until now. When I install VirtualBox now with the command line (apt install virtualbox) I'll get the same error as in my first post (" VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up correctly.", "Please reinstall virtualbox-dkms package and load the kernel module...") as soon as I'm trying to launch any VM.

In terminal, run the following to update Ubuntu and its packages, and to reinstall VirtualBox (VB). Before doing so, make a copy of any existing VB environments, lest they be accidentally deleted.

Remove the old installation:
sudo apt remove virtualbox
sudo apt remove virtualbox-dkms


Get updates and delete cruft:
sudo apt -y update && sudo apt -y full-upgrade
sudo apt -y autoremove --purge


Fix missing packages:
sudo apt update --fix-missing
sudo apt install -f


Repair broken packages
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo dpkg -l | grep ^..R

The above returns a list of packages that need to be removed. Remove each as follows:
sudo dpkg --purge --force-all <package_name>


Clean up remainders:
sudo apt clean


Update yet, again:
sudo apt -y update


Open Synaptic Package Manager and check for any remaining broken packages:

Hopefully, there won't be any marked broken in the Status column.

Now either install the Ubuntu version of VirtualBox:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r) dkms
sudo apt install virtualbox-7.0 -y

Or
Add VirtualBox directly from the Oracle repository and install Ubuntu from there:
With a browser, download Oracle's VirtualBox for Ubuntu 22.04 and install from terminal:
sudo apt install virtualbox-7.0_7.0.20-163906~Ubuntu~jammy_amd64.deb

Or
Add Oracle as PPA:
curl https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc | gpg --dearmor > oracle_vbox_2016.gpg
curl https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc | gpg --dearmor > oracle_vbox.gpg
sudo install -o root -g root -m 644 oracle_vbox_2016.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
sudo install -o root -g root -m 644 oracle_vbox.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ 
echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian $(lsb_release -sc) contrib" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list

Install VirtualBox from Oracle, itself:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r) dkms
sudo apt install virtualbox-7.0 -y


Add VirtualBox Extendsion, e.g., for USB access, encryption, etc.:
wget https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/7.0.0/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-7.0.0.vbox-extpack
sudo VBoxManage extpack install Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-7.0.0.vbox-extpack




Thanks. I tried 1.-7.: No errors, no broken packages. However, at 8. I cannot install VirtualBox 7.0 or any other specific version ("Unable to locate package"). Only "apt install virtualbox" does work and installs version 6.1.32, with the same errors. In the installation process at "starting LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module", an error " Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module" is logged.

@ecmascript, have you tried the alternative, "add VirtualBox directly from the Oracle repository and install Ubuntu from there?" Since you can download the Debian packages directly from Oracle, https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/7.0.20/virtualbox-7.0_7.0.20-163906~Ubuntu~jammy_amd64.deb, there should be no "Unable to locate package" message.

Yes, but curl is not installed on my machine and when I tried to install it, I get another error for a missing dependency. Can I pipe the *.asc files manually (I've downloaded them) into gpg --dearmor > oracle_vbox_2016.gpg, without using curl for the download?

If you cannot even install curl, as simple as sudo apt install curl, then many essential files are now missing from Ubuntu! At this point, I'd suggest saving data and reinstalling Ubuntu 22.04 (or now, 24.04).
